# How to track invoice/journal/lead status changes in Odoo for storing in data warehouse

Tags: odoo, data-warehouse

I am about to build a data warehouse from an Odoo instance, I am not sure how to track the previous status of the invoices, journals, or leads. I am pulling data from the *account.move* but it has only the current state.
I am looking for another model(table) which has the status change information.

Comment: Hint: look into `mail.tracking.value` and [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/backend/mixins.html#logging-changes).

Comment: All i see is mails and notifications. I checked *mail.tracking.value* and *mail.activity*

Comment: You can activate "tracking" of fields in odoo with the mentioned feature. Some fields are already tracked and create chatter messages in odoo show how field values have changed. Those changes are stored in table `mail_tracking_value` which has a relation to `mail_message` which has a relation to the desired business models like `account.move`. If you want another logging/tracking feature take a look into the [auditlog module](https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/16.0/auditlog) of the OCA. But Odoo's native feature should be enough for your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I found the details in `mail.messenger.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`account.move` and `crm.lead` has column named message_ids which contains ids of records to `mail.messenger`. Each id contains state change related information and other information related to messaging.